# Function to run KaplanMeier model(Python)

Tags: python, function, loops, survival-analysis

In my dataset data1, I have a column Region, with 3 categories:Asia, Europe, North America. Now I'm trying to fit in a KM model for survival analysis of certain machine parts belonging to these 3 regions. The variable being used is number of hours of operation before the machines collapse. I've used the following code, which runs fine:

```
T=data1['op_hours']
Region_Asia=(data1['Region'] == 'ASIA')
Region_EUROPE=(data1['Region'] == 'EUROPE')
Region_NORTH=(data1['Region'] == 'NORTH AMERICA')
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
kmf.fit(T[Region_Asia], label="Asia")
kmf.plot(ax=ax,ci_force_lines=False)
kmf.fit(T[Region_EUROPE], label="Europe")
kmf.plot(ax=ax, ci_force_lines=False)
kmf.fit(T[Region_NORTH], label="North America")
kmf.plot(ax=ax, ci_force_lines=False)
plt.ylim(0, 1);
plt.title("Lifespans of different machines")
```

I get the following plot:
[image]

Now, I'm trying to create a function so that I won't have to write separate lines of codes for each of the categories in order to obtain the KM fit. I've tried this:

```
def Kaplan(c):
    a=[]
    u=[]
    u=c.unique()
    T=data1['op_hours']
    from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
    kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    for i in range(len(u)):
        a=u[i]
        kmf.fit(T[a])
        kmf.plot(ax=ax,ci_force_lines=False)
        plt.ylim(0, 1);
        plt.title("Lifespans of different machines")

Kaplan(data1.Region)
```

I'm getting: `KeyError: 'ASIA'`
Can somebody help me out here, I'm still a newbie in coding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `T` doesn't have `ASIA` inside, and `a` at one point, is `'ASIA'`.

Comment: Right, any idea how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your given code at the beginning, you can do this

```
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter

def Kaplan(dt, time, regions):
    tobefit = lambda region: dt[time][(dt['Region'] == region)]
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
    for region in regions:
        kmf.fit(tobefit(region), label=region)
        kmf.plot(ax=ax,ci_force_lines=False)
    plt.ylim(0, 1);
    plt.title("Lifespans of different machines")

Kaplan(data1, "op_hours", ["Asia", "Europe", "North America"])
```

**Update**

If you have fixed parameters and do not want to type them every time you invoke the function. You can define the function with default parameters

```
def Kaplan(dt, time="op_hours", regions=["Asia", "Europe", "North America"]):
    tobefit = lambda region: dt[time][(dt['Region'] == region)]
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()
    for region in regions:
        kmf.fit(tobefit(region), label=region)
        kmf.plot(ax=ax,ci_force_lines=False)
    plt.ylim(0, 1);
    plt.title("Lifespans of different machines")

# Then you can call your Kaplan function without specifying time and regions  
Kaplan(data1)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for this--but I'm getting the following error after running it: ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

Comment: No no sorry, it worked..thanks a lot :) just another query-- is it anyway possible to run it without me having to specify the categories(Asia,Europe,America)?

Comment: @DChy I think it is possible, if you want to plot all regions within your data. You just first get a list of all regions from your data and then loop through them using the same way. If you just want to plot certain region, you have anyway to specify what you want

Comment: @DChy Or, you can define your function with default argument as def Kaplan(data1, time="op_hours", regions=["Asia", "Europe", "North America"]), see update

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy :)